# SQL moving average using output

Tags: sql, hive

Assume there is a table comprises 3 rows:

```
date      num
05-01      1
05-02      2
05-03      3
```

Then,calculate its 3-day moving average using new values. For example:

```
1st result = (1+2+3)/3=2
2nd result = (2+3+2)/3=2.33
3rd result = (3+2+2.33)/3=2.43
4th result = (2+2.33+2.43)/3=2.25
5th result = (2.33+2.43+2.25)/3=2.34

....till the 30th result
```

Is is possible to implement this in SQL? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See if any of the answers here help you with this task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922379/sql-query-for-7-day-rolling-average-in-sql-server

Comment: @Spittin' IT Thanks for your reply, but it seems to me that 'avg() over()' only suits fixed values...

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a table with 30 rows, seeding the first 3 with your given values, and the use a recursive CTE that incorporates a window function to calculate the average and an INSERT statement to add the new row to the table.